# RemoteApp file menu shows in alternate location with multi monitor

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp, monitors, windows

I deployed RDS on Windows 2012R2 Servers.  I used that for publishing RemoteApp. RemoteApp works just fine.  However, I run into display issue on multi monitors with applications (Notepad, Wordpad, 3rd party applications).  If I have Notepad openS and expandS it across two monitorS. I clicked on File Menu and the drop down will show in alternate location of the screen.  If I move Notepad to the 2nd monitor, the File Menu will show black arrow.  I saw other people has the same problem on the web but there wasn't a solution.  I wonder if anyone run into the same problem and have a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Is this more of an end user problem? Is there support or documentation that could help out in this situation?

Comment: I opened a case with MS and was told the bug was fixed in W2k8R2. The issue didn't occur in Windows 2012. But the issue with Windows 2012R2.

Answer (score 2):

We are seeing something similar as well on RemoteApp 2012 servers.

If you drag the app to the primary monitor you see the full menu exploded on the alternate you see a scroll bar. If you only have one item, you can't see menu item without scrolling.